# Triangle ruler for OS X

Tags: macos, on-screen-keyboard, ruler

With all the mathematics required in games or apps, why is there no such application like [TriangleRuler](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/triangleruler/id488576675?mt=8) for Mac OS X? Or Windows? Or cross-platform?

**[edit] I myself am looking for a tool for Mac OS X or a cross-platform tool.**

> [image]

It would be a really handy tool to just be able to figure out an angle on screen, without
having to write your own debug-graphics-class or functions or whatever.

Comment: There is vertical ruler. http://www.pascal.com/software/freeruler/ But so far i could not find any triangular ruler.....

Comment: Why was this question closed?. It is pretty useful.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows : Try [MB-Ruler - the triangular screen ruler](http://www.markus-bader.de/MB-Ruler/screenshot.htm). You can measure angles as well as angular distance using it. A perfect tool.

> [image]

For Mac :Try Onde rulers. http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/38923/onde-rulers/

It is also good, but paid one. You can try it for 15 days.There are lot of rulers like vertical ruler, protractor etc. Here is their website, http://www.ondesoft.com

Comment: Nice! This is what i'm looking for. However, do you also know of a crossplatform or mac OSX application for this? In my hurry i did not specify that i myself was on the OSX platform... edited question accordingly.

Comment: For mac i know only Horizontal-vetical ruler. Coudnot find anything like this. I will try and get back.http://www.pascal.com/software/freeruler/

Comment: Got the right tool. Edited my answer. Please check it and let me know.

Comment: Nice! i guess i do not have enough googleFu :) i also noticed the pixelstick app, trying that out aswell! will get back about it!

Comment: :P You should have searched using right keywords.